# Firebase database and search functionality

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need a help in firebase database, 
I am willing to create an app for a city like Kolkata, to find buses between different local stations, I want to save the data in database and user will input where to where they want to go, after clicking on search, list of available data will be shown, 
But I need help in how should I save the data to fetch it easily with less complicated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save data easily with firebase

```
private void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
    User user = new User(name, email);
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}
```

You can search from firebase like below

```
DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("users").orderByChild("name").equalTo("Fazal");
query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);

ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            //TODO get the data here
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
    {

    }
};
```

**EDIT:**

Firebase dont have a great SQL like searches built in. You can either sort by values/key or you can equalto

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data

for further details check fire-base documentation

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: I actually need data  filter, user will give two input and have to find nodes which have child user inputs, will be shown to the user

Comment: Ok , I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when you write data into firebase database used below code ..

make pojo class for insert data..

```
public class City {
public String name, code;

public City(String name, String code) {
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
}
```

}

then after when you insert data into firebase used below code..

```
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register_layout);
    mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("usersDb/UserTable");//define your database name and table name

}
```

// below method used insert data..

```
    private void insertData(){
    City city=new City("Ahmedabad","380016"); // you can add data also runtime.
    mFirebaseDatabase.child(city.name).setValue(user);

}
```

// below method used to search data..

```
    private void sqlQuery(){
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Query query = reference.child("usersDb").child("UserTable").orderByChild("name").equalTo("vikas@gmail.com");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                for (DataSnapshot issue : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d("Value::",issue.getValue(User.class).email);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```